# background image not showing properly after uploading

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, background-image

after uploading my page, the background image doesnt show properly.

I tried to see it with the debug console and it says that the background-image(bg.png) has a status of: 304 not modified. I don't understand this and dont know anyway to solve this.

hope you guys can help me!

Here is my website: [Link](http://bermudastudios.nl/junske/)

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    background: url(../images/bg.png) repeat center center fixed; 
}
```

bg.png = 99x99pixels, 6.11KB

Comment: 304 means it is saved in cache. You can refresh your cache with CTRL+F5. If you always want a new image you can postfix your image url  with a ?+timestamp. Nice site btw I'm dutch too ;)

Comment: it works fine by me, EDIT: it stoped working its like random

Comment: @A1rPun i tried the CTRL+F5, but it stills shows the black stripes. thank you :)

Comment: Can you show us your CSS code where bg.png is added?. And the size of the raw image? Looks like you have it in a style sheet.

Comment: I used your body css with a standard image that I use (100x100) and it works fine. I'm wondering if it might be something in your image file itself. Any chance you could upload it to imgur or some other site where we might download and play with it?

Comment: @TimSPQR the point is when I try it locally, it works all fine. but when I upload the page to my server. the background image is not covering the whole page. instead of that, you see the background image with black/white stripes underneath it.

here is the image link : http://imgur.com/jFST7B0

Comment: Then there must be an issue with your server. Try different background images and see what happens.

Comment: @TimSPQR still the same though :(. I tried it with a custom 100x100px bg, saved for web, non-interlaced, PNG format.

Comment: your demo page is down, have you solved this issue?